# No callbacks being called after Camera.takePicture()

Tags: java, android, callback

After following the steps given by the Android API documentation, I am not getting any callbacks after calling Camera.takePicture() (no shutter callback or image callback).  I have the correct permissions declared in the manifest, I am not getting any exceptions, and I am able to use this code for recording videos.  Similar questions to this issue have been regarding just the `Camera.PictureCallback` not being called but I haven't found any questions where the `Camera.ShutterCallback` isn't called.  Here is my code:

```
    private class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
            Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.ShutterCallback {

        protected SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public CameraPreview() {
            super(VideoActivity.this);
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // Deprecated setting is required for API < 11
            // Automatically set for API >= 11, no issue with continuing to use it
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Surface is created");
            try {
                mCamera = getCamera();
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera created when surface was created");
                if(mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.lock();
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Preview Started");
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException in setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken called");
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if(pictureFile == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error creating media file");
                return;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Writing to file: " + pictureFile);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShuttter is called");
    }
}
```

An instance of that class gets initialized in onStart() and is stored in an instance variable called `mPreview`.  `mPreview` implements the Camera callback interfaces so I can use them in this way.  The `CameraPreview` class has been working for recording videos.
The logic for taking the picture:

```
mCamera.lock();
mCamera.takePicture(mPreview, null, mPreview);
Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Picture Taken",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.d(TAG, "Picture Taken");
```

So my question is, why am I not getting any callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue a while ago and forgot to share it so here it is:

I needed to call `mCamera.reconnect()` after `mCamera.startPreview()` and before `mCamera.takePicture()`.  I believe this is because I was receiving callbacks from another process to take the picture and reconnect needs to be called after the camera is used by another process.